# No internet connection on virtualbox

Tags: networking

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and internet connection was working without any problem until today. I can ping from my comp. to virtualbox without any problem but not vice versa.

I restarted network but problem is still here.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

What can be the problem here?

**EDIT:**

Bridged Adapter and Name to the device selected as network adapter.